# How does Gradle 'war' plugin know to invoke Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, war

I've looked around quite a lot, and I can't seem to find a straight answer to this question.  How does the Gradle 'war' plugin know how and when to invoke the Spring Framework?

For example, when using the `war` plugin task to compile a project (such as [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-4-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/)), at what point is the Spring Framework invoked to process the `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` annotations to produce the properly compiled servlets?  Is Gradle hard-wired to recognize Spring Framework?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The war plugin packages your class files into a deployable web archive. It is unpacked by your web provider, i.e. Tomcat, and invoked at that point through your various properties and XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that happens at runtime, either via classpath scanning or via `@Configuration` beans. There exist annotation processors, but I am not aware of any one that can convert the Spring annotations into the XML configuration files that is the other Spring configuration system.

In your example, the class that extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is autodetected by a Servlet 3.0+ container (jetty in this case) because that container reads the WAR first.

That `ServletInitializer` then proceeds to spin up Spring, using the provided classes as roots; Spring checks all the annotations and builds the `Environment` and all the beans.

As you see, this does not have anything to do with Gradle or any other build system.